# java- how to avoid concurrency and other errors when using set - hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using the following code to iterate through a hashmap- name of hashmap variable='context'

```
            Iterator iter = context.keySet().iterator();

            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
                String keystring = (String)iter.next();
                String varname= keystring.substring(0, keystring.indexOf("~"));
                String level= keystring.substring(keystring.indexOf("~")+1);
                    Integer levelno= Integer.parseInt(level);

                if(levelno==curr_level+1)
                {
                    iter.remove();
                    //we have found a variable of current level... this has to be removed from hashmap...
                    //context.remove(keystring);
                    //also the same variable has to be removed from the script engine as well...
                    scriptEngine.removeVariable(varname);

                }

            }
```

Is the above code correct, esp with regards to removal of data from the hashmap? Because when I run the program, then at different (random) values in the hashmap an error message is generated that a specific value (in the hashmap) could not be found(That code is separate and used in conjunction with the above code).
With ref to above code, what do I have to keep in mind, to avoid errors when deleting data from a hashmap?

Comment: Is `context` being used from multiple threads?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a correct way of removing values without breaking the iterator.

However, this does not mean that there cannot be a logic error in the whole application, other than in the code already shown.